# Kак изменить конфигурацю чтобы запросы дублировались на другой адрес?

Tags: nginx

Ситуация - планируется ввод полностью переписанного сервиса сбора статистики.

После прохождения всех тестов есть желание выкатить его в реальную среду, из реальных возможностей - изменить конфигурацию Nginx.

Вопрос - можно ли как-то изменить конфигурацю Nginx так, чтобы запросы **дублировались** на другой адрес (не перенаправлялись!), при этом никакого логирования этих запросов происходить не должно (или должно писаться в дополнительный лог)?

Answer (score 0):

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_mirror_module.html

Кажется, нашел в новой версии